# Why does swap! try again even when an Atom's value hasn't changed?

Tags: concurrency, clojure

Suppose I have the following piece of (contrived) Clojure code:

```
(def c (clojure.lang.Atom. [nil nil]))
(swap! c 
   (fn [[x y]] 
       ["done", (second (swap! c (fn [[x y]] [x y])))]))
```

I would expect this to work as follows:

1. Clojure unboxes `c` to find `[nil nil]`, and passes it to the outer `fn`.
2. The outer `fn` calls `swap!`, which unboxes `c` to find `[nil nil]`, and passes this value to the inner `fn`.
3. The inner `fn` returns `[nil nil]`. The inner call to `swap!` swaps this in for the new value of `c`.
4. The outer `fn` returns the value `["done" nil]`.
5. The outer `swap!` tries to `compare-and-set!`, and sees that the current value of `c`, `[nil nil]`, is the same as the old value, `[nil nil]`, so it succeeds, swapping in `["done" nil]`.

But in fact, this code loops forever: the outer loop keeps retrying.

Why is this? What's missing from my mental model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple people on the Clojure Slack helped me understand what was going on here (thanks!). `compare-and-set!` uses `identical?` (i.e., Java reference equality) to compare the old and new values of an atom. Every time I recreate the vector `[x y]`, I am creating a new object, which is not `identical?` to the old one. Even though I don't think of the inner `swap!` as mutating anything, technically it is.